# Admin URL "broken" after updating Domain Name

Tags: admin, magento-2.2.5

**Aim**

Update Domain Name of M2 instance from `example.co` to `beta.example.com`

**Steps**

So, I changed the Domain Name of my Magento 2 store using the following commands:

`bin/magento setup:store-config:set --base-url="http://beta.example.com/"`

`bin/magento setup:store-config:set --base-url-secure="https://beta.example.com/"`

`bin/magento cache:flush`

`bin/magento cache:clean`

**Result**

This worked fine, until the next day. When I tried to load my admin url (`http://beta.example.com/admin`), I was forwarded to the below URL with this error:

- `http://beta.example.com/admin/http:/admin/admin/index/index/key/1a2376cc1c89ea53ca4a903003d3a4859b5c62347cc763a6c0105ea3bae466e/`
- "**This page isn’t working** beta.example.com redirected you too many times."

Regardless of trying to load `http://beta.example.com/admin` after clearing cookies on different Browsers and Devices, I couldn't get past this point.

**Temporary Workaround**

In order to resolve this, I have to clear the cache by running the below commands.

`bin/magento cache:flush`

`bin/magento cache:clean`

This seems to work for a bit until I go to load the backend the next day. I can't even reproduce the error until the next day...

Any ideas what could be causing this? Or even why my temp workaround only works for a few hours?

**Notes: Day 1**

The only thing I can think of that happens overnight is Indexing *(maybe)*. So, I've ran the below command. Will report back in 24 hours

`bin/magento indexer:reindex`

**Notes: Day 2**

Indexing had no affect. Admin URL still reset to "broke" the next day. I'll try clearing all cache folders today using the below command. Will report back in 24 hours

`rm -rf var/page_cache var/cache var/generation var/div var/view_preprocessed generated/metadata/* generated/code/*`

**Notes: Day 3**

No affect. Tried updating Admin URL to see if that does anything with:

`bin/magento setup:config:set --backend-frontname="admin_path"`

**Notes: Day 4**

No affect.

**Notes: Day 5**

I've narrowed down that it's `config` that requires either Cleaning of Flushing with either command.:

`bin/magento cache:clean config` or `bin/magento cache:flush config`

I've yet to determine what changes over ~24hrs for me to have to keep doing this though.

Comment: What you have here Log in to the Admin Panel, choose Stores>Settings>Configuration. And in app/etc/env.php in admin line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having checked the DB Table (`core_config_data`), I noticed that my base URL was correct, so I never thought anything of it. I then realised after that the `web/unsecure/base_url` and `web/secure/base_url` entries were for `scope_id = 1`. There was no entry for `scope_id = 0`.

**So, what I did was simply go into the backend of Magento to `Stores > Configuration > General > Web` and Press the `Save Config` button.**

This then generated 2 new records in the `core_config_data` table under `scope_id = 0`. Since then, I've not come across the issue. Based on the fix, I'm surprised the problem didn't stop me from accessing any of the site at all.